saving xml state and restoring it
I have an app written in Kotlin, which has a navigation bar. To show content from each tab I use fragments. On one of them I have 3 buttons and progress bar. When I navigate to other tab and then go back on this slide with progress bar, all style of buttons (when they clicked once they become unclickable and their background changes), progress of progress bar, all of it become default.
So, I want to save buttons' and progress' state to restore it when restarting the app or navigating in the app
P.S: Sorry for my bad English and for wording of a question (I'm newbie in android developing)

To retain the state of your buttons and progress bar in a Fragment when navigating within your app or restarting it, you need to save the state of these UI elements and restore it appropriately.
You have some options like (Just example):

Saving State on Fragment Level
Saving State on App Level (Shared Preferences/Any DB)

Step 1: Override onSaveInstanceState to Save the State
Override the onSaveInstanceState method in your Fragment to save the state of the buttons and progress bar.


override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outState.putBoolean(BUTTON_1_STATE_KEY, button1.isEnabled
    outState.putInt(PROGRESS_BAR_STATE_KEY, progressBar.progress)
}

Step 2: Restore State in onViewCreated
Check the saved instance state in the onViewCreated method and restore the state of the buttons and progress bar.

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    // Restore state
    savedInstanceState?.let {
        button1.isEnabled = it.getBoolean(BUTTON_1_STATE_KEY, true)
        progressBar.progress = it.getInt(PROGRESS_BAR_STATE_KEY, 0)
    }


I've tried it but it does not work. my savedInstanceState is null


To preserve the state of your buttons and progress bar when navigating between fragments or restarting the app, you can use the ViewModel to store UI-related data in a lifecycle-conscious way. This helps in maintaining the UI state during configuration changes like screen rotations, and when navigating back and forth between different fragments.


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Normally we store the ui state as data variables inside a ViewModel. and the view always renders the UI depending upon the current data in the ViewModel.
But we can't move everything inside a ViewModel. For example the scroll position of recycler view. So in such cases, play with the UI components. For example in the above scenario:

You should also use the ViewPager2 with a FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Use onSaveInstanceState() to store any values that you want to restore when the app comes to the foreground from the background state.



first is deprecated so I've tried second way. but as I got from debugger, savedInstanceState is always null
